# Optional variables in an sql query string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am automating excel and I have a string which I read input from the sheet as Variable1,2,3,4,5,6

I wish to make them optional if they are left empty the query executes as usual

```
  SELECT LEFT(Name, 5) 
  FROM Production.Product
  where 
  product.name like 'Variable1'
  product.brand like 'Variable2'
  prodcut.price > 'Variable3'
  prodcut.expirydate > 'Variable4'
  ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, 5) 
FROM Production.Product
WHERE
(Product.name like @Variable1 or @Variable1 IS NULL) AND
(Product.brand like @Variable2 or @Variable2 IS NULL) AND
(Product.price > @Variable3 or @Variable3 IS NULL) AND
(Product.expirydate > @Variable4 or @Variable4 IS NULL)
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Comment: One remark. The order of the operations is important in this case. Writing (Product.name like Variable1 or Variable1 IS NULL) doesn't equal (Variable1 IS NULL OR Product.name like Variable1) because the moment the first part is evaluated and always returns true, the second doesn't get evaluated anymore and LIKE is a high cost/slow operation if the DB is big enough thus it shouldn't be the first to be evaluated

Comment: Skorpioh; Not in my experience, though I use SQL Server, which may work a little differently to MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, you're right. I just checked in MSSQL and it's smarter than I thought and gets it right either way :)

Answer (score 0):

The below query should do the trick:

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, 5) 
FROM Production.Product
WHERE
  ('Variable1' = '' OR product.name LIKE 'Variable1') AND
  ('Variable2' = '' OR product.brand LIKE 'Variable2') AND
  ('Variable3' = '' OR prodcut.price > 'Variable3') AND
  ('Variable4' = '' OR prodcut.expirydate > 'Variable4')
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Your query however doesn't look healthy ATM. One that might run on MySQL and MSSQL would look like:

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, 5) 
FROM Production.Product
WHERE
  (@Variable1 = '' OR product.name LIKE @Variable1) AND
  (@Variable2 = '' OR product.brand LIKE @Variable2) AND
  (@Variable3 = '' OR prodcut.price > @Variable3) AND
  (@Variable4 = '' OR @Variable4 IS NULL OR prodcut.expirydate > @Variable4)
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Still, you first have to decide the data type of the variables which might still change the query and you'll also have to add the '*' and/or '%' wildcards to the strings you're throwing at LIKE or else it doesn't make much sense and an '=' would be much faster.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: What if a `@Variable` is `NULL`?  `NULL <> ''` after all.

Comment: You are partially right - @Variable might or might not be null. In this case these variables come from excel so it is likely not going to be null. I also mentioned that the where clause might change based on the type declaration thus if the variables are declared as NOT NULL then saying <> '' is enough; else it need the empty as well as the null check.